# R - 'NA' text treated as N/A

Tags: r, text, na

I have a data frame in R including country iso codes. The iso code for Namibia happens to be 'NA'. R treats this text 'NA' as N/A.

For example the code below gives me the row with Namibia.

```
test <- subset(country.info,is.na(country.info$iso.code))
```

I initially thought it might be a factor issue, so I made sure the iso code column is character. But this didn't help.

How can this be solved?

Answer (score 6):

This probably relates to how you read in the data. Just because it's character doesn't mean your `"NA"` isn't an `NA`, e.g.:

```
z <- c("NA",NA,"US")
class(z)
#[1] "character"
```

You could confirm this by giving us a `dput()` of (part of) your data.

When you read in your data, try changing `na.strings = "NA"` (e.g., in `read.csv`) to something else and see if it works.

For example, with `na.strings = ""`:

```
read.table(text="code country
NA  Namibia
GR  Germany
FR  France", stringsAsFactors=FALSE, header=TRUE, na.strings="")
#   code country
# 1   NA Namibia
# 2   GR Germany
# 3   FR  France
```

Make sure to check that the use of `""` doesn't result in changing anything else. Else, you can use a string that will definitely not occur in your file like "z_z_z" or something like that.. You can replace the `text=..` with your file name.

Comment: old answer new question: is it possible to specify `na.strings` per column? In a table (where we don't have control over the identity of the NA string) there might be numeric columns with real NA values. Would be nice to be able to suppress NA interpretation per column...

Comment: @dojuba I don't think so. You could look into whether `readr::read_csv()`, etc. support that.

Answer (score 0):

If Thomas' solution doesn't work you can always use the `countrycode` package to change your countrycodes to something that causes fewer problems. 
In your case from ISO2-character to ISO3-character for instance.

`country.info$iso.code<-countrycode(country.info$iso.code,"iso2c","iso3c",                                       warn=TRUE)`

If `iso2c` causes problems use `country.names`, hoping the Republic of Congo and the Democratic Republic of Congo don't mess things up.