# "NA" string converted into <NA>

Tags: r, csv, dataframe

I have a `csv` file with country names and their iso codes. Here's what it looks like:

```
"Name","Code"
"Afghanistan","AF"
"Albania","AL"
"Algeria","DZ"
"Namibia","NA"
```

I read it in a `data.frame` using the following code:

```
cc = read.csv("countries.csv", header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE, 
                                           colClasses = c("character"))
```

Here's what the data looks like:

```
Name         Code
Afghanistan  AF
Albania      AL
Algeria      DZ
Namibia      <NA>
```

The string `"NA"` is getting converted to `<NA>` even though I explicitly set  `colClasses = c("character")`.

How do I get `"NA"` to show as `"NA"` in the `data.frame`?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17990233/r-na-text-treated-as-n-a

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try setting the `na.strings` parameter explicitly - the default is"NA":

```
    cc = read.csv("countries.csv", header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE,
                              colClasses = c("character"),  na.strings="" )
```

Comment: Thanks! This works for `data.table()` too, for anyone (like me) using that instead of dataframes.