# NA for country code Namibia in query line R

Tags: r

I have this code to read from a database table.
I have almost all countries there including Namibia with code NA.

The area code NA is considered as a non available value in R.
Is there a way in this code to tell the program that he should consider this dimension REF_AREA and COUNTERPART_AREA as character directly there.

I put a patch of course later on the change the na to an invented code and I have to reverse it when creating the csv file for laoding afterwards.

```
  getITS_R = function(prod_stage = "R"){
  ch <- odbcConnect("FIGARO", uid="figaro", pwd="figaro88", believeNRows=FALSE)
  query <- paste0("select *  from ITS6_INPUT where PROD_STAGE = '", prod_stage,"' and UNIT_MEASURE = 'EUR' ;")
  its6_input = data.table(sqlQuery(ch, query, as.is = TRUE))
  return(its6_input)
  close(ch)
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: here is a similar problem. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31121320/na-string-converted-into-na. I think you can solve your problem in a similar way using the 'na.strings' argument of sqlQuery()

Comment: let's try `data.table(sqlQuery(ch, query, as.is = TRUE, na.strings=""))`

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["NA" string converted into <NA>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31121320/na-string-converted-into-na)